# SUM numbers, but when 0, add 8 instead

Tags: excel, function, sum

I'm trying to write a SUM(IF(zero, add 8), A1:G1) kind of excel function.
What it should do:

- If the **cell contains a number**, add that number to the sum.
- If the **cell contains a number = 0**, add 8 to the sum.
- if the **cell is empty**, add nothing to the sum

I have tried using SUMIF, but it only "adds the numbers if they meet a criteria", and I rather need "add *this* when the criteria is met"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make a longer formula:

```
=SUM(A1:G1)+COUNTIF(A1:G1, 0)*8
```

The first sum will only do your numbers ignore blanks and 0's, the second part counts the number of 0's and multiplies it by 8.

Comment: wasn't sure about the 0 as some functions will act on empty cells like it is 0... :P

Comment: Because of splitting hairs: for what reason the outher brackets? `x + (y * z) = x + y * z` :P

Comment: Haha touche, my BIDMAS, BODMAS (or whatever alternative) is clearly not taking part today!

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1

If you can spare another column, just use an IF statement to replace all 0's by 8's and blanks by 0's (not really necessary) in a new column
`=IF(A1=0,8,A1)` and take a SUM of this column.

## Method 2

Just SUM  over your original data, count the number of zeros in your data and multiply this number by 8.

```
=SUM(A1:A10)+8*COUNTIF(A1:A10,"=0")
```

Note: The data is in A1:A10 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(A1:G1,">0")+8*COUNTIFS(A1:G1,0,A1:G1,"<>")
```

should be self-explaining :)

Comment: Why use `SUMIF` greater than 0, surely anything plus 0 is the same value, so you can just sum the whole range. Also blank ranges should add nothing, so shouldn't be included in the COUNTIF.

Comment: @TimWilkinson just done by phone... in theory also `=SUM(A1:G1)+8*COUNTIF(A1:G1,0)` should work... but can't test it right now...

Comment: @TimWilkinson I assume you tested it and it does work :D

Comment: Ha i'm just splitting hairs (apart from the `COUNTIF "<>"` bit), not tested because it will clearly work :)